# How do I neatly bind Cocoa inputs to NSDocument properties?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, data-binding, appkit

Let's say I have a simple NSDocument subclass:

```
@interface Document : NSDocument
@property NSString *someText;
@end
```

I want to map `someText` to some field in my view - so I add a new field to my view controller:

```
@interface ViewController : NSViewController
@property Document* document;
@end
```

...and make sure to store my document:

```
- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
    self.document = ((Document*)representedObject);    
}
```

Oh yeah, and I make sure that the document property is dynamic, which a bit of googling brought up as important for data binding:

```
@implementation Document
@dynamic someText;
@end
```

Then head on over to my NSTextField and *try* to bind the value:

[image: A screenshot of XCode binding interface failing to recognize a Model Key Path]

As you can see, it reports that "Xcode cannot resolve the entered keypath." Furthermore, the "Controller Key" field (which I believe is where I'm *supposed* to specify `document`, with `self.someText` for the keypath?) is entirely greyed out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Xcode cannot resolve the entered keypath" does not mean "The binding doesn't work at runtime". The "Controller Key" is a key for binding to Cocoa bindings–compatible controller classes like `NSObjectController`, `NSArrayController` and `NSTreeController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `@dynamic` isn't necessary - what *is* necessary is that the view controller's `representedObject` is set quite early.

I modified the default generated `makeWindowControllers` in the Document class so that it sets `representedObject` on the just-created WindowController's contentViewController *before* `addWindowController` is invoked:

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers {        
    NSWindowController *wc = [[NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Document Window Controller"];
    wc.contentViewController.representedObject = self;
    [self addWindowController:wc];    
}
```

And then, in my storyboard, I simply bound to `View Controller` with a Model Key Path of `representedObject.someText`. (Be sure to check off "Continuously Updates Value" if things still don't seem to be changing - otherwise the data model might only be updated on certain events such as focus change.)

Comment: See [Continuously Updates Value](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/Concepts/BindingsOptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002304-187448) "A Boolean value that determines whether the value of the binding is updated as edits are made to the user interface item or is updated only when the user interface item resigns as the responder.".